# How to count the occurrences of sets which are part of a list in Python?

Tags: python, data-mining

Trying to implement the apriori algorithm and made it to the point where I can extract the subsets occurring together in all transactions.

This is what I have:

```
subsets = [set(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Breakfast & Brunch']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Breakfast & Brunch']), set(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Restaurants'])]
```

For example `set(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants'])` occurs twice
and I need to keep track of the numbers of occurrences together with the corresponding patterns.

I tried to use:

```
from collections import Counter

support_set = Counter()
# some code that generated the list above

support_set.update(subsets)
```

but it generates this error:

```
  supported = itemsets_support(transactions, candidates)
  File "apriori.py", line 77, in itemsets_support
    support_set.update(subsets)
  File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 567, in update
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Any idea?

Comment: That probably is not Apriori anymore, what you are implementing, but a naive and inefficient approximation of the 'frequent itemset' idea. Benchmark with some larger data set against e.g. ELKI, or R's `arules` package. Putting everything into a `Counter` does not scale. Try e.g. the supermarket data set.

Comment: It is part of Apriori. If it scales or not that's a different problem.At this point is it not built for production, yet!

Comment: No, it's not. Apriori is about not doing this inefficiently, but efficiently. If you ignore the efficiency aspects, it's not Apriori anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn the sets to [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instances which are hashable:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> subsets = [set(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Breakfast & Brunch']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Breakfast & Brunch']), set(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants']), set(['American (Traditional)', 'Restaurants'])]
>>> c = Counter(frozenset(s) for s in subsets)
>>> c
Counter({frozenset(['American (Traditional)', 'Restaurants']): 2, frozenset(['Breakfast & Brunch', 'Restaurants']): 2, frozenset(['American (Traditional)', 'Breakfast & Brunch']): 2})
```